# How to use awaitReactions in guildMemberAdd

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I send messages to users when they connect to my server, and I want to continue authorization by clicking on reactions.
How can I create this? I'm using the following code:

```
robot.on("guildMemberAdd", (gMembAdd) =>
{ 
      gMembAdd.send(`Hi ${gMembAdd.toString()} welcome to the server Test`).then(msg => {
       msg.react('✅')
      .then(() => msg.react('❎'));  
//--------------------Developmend-------------------------------------
  let filter = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === '✅' || reaction.emoji.name === '❎'; 

  let col = msg.createReactionCollector(filter); 

  col.on('collect', r => 
  {
      if (r.users.last().id !== msg.author.id)
      {
      gMembAdd.addRole(gMembAdd.guild.roles.find("name", "Autorize")).catch(console.error)

      r.remove(r.users.last().id); 

     console.log(` ${gMembAdd.user.id} и ${gMembAdd.user.username} and ${r.emoji}`);
      }
  });         

  //--------------------------------------------------------------------
  });
```

I need a reaction check and role assignment if the response is positive and kick if not. I don't understand how to continue.

Will this code be used correctly?

Comment: Have you figured this out or do you still need help?

Comment: @AndreasGassmann Hi, I still need your help. I updated the code, this is what I have. Help me pls. Thanks for answering

Answer (score 1):

To check the reaction you can use [`MesssageReaction.emoji.name`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ReactionEmoji?scrollTo=name), as you did above.
For the other thing, you can use [`GuildMember.addRole()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=addRole) & [`GuildMember.kick()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=kick).
Here's a sample you can check out:

```
robot.on('guildMemberAdd', async member => {
  let msg = await member.send(`Hi ${member} welcome to the server Test`);
  await msg.react('✅');
  await msg.react('❎');

  msg.createReactionCollection(r => ['✅', '❎'].includes(r.emoji.name))
    .on('collect', r => { 
      if (r.emoji.name == '✅') 
        member.addRole(member.guild.roles.find("name", "Authorize"))
          .then(() => { console.log(`Added ${member.user.username} (${member.id}).`); })
          .catch(console.error);
      else if (r.emoji.name == '❎') member.kick("You got rejected.");

      r.remove(r.users.last());
    });
});
```

You can also use [`Message.awaitReactions()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=awaitReactions), which is better because it doesn't go on after the reaction is added:

```
robot.on('guildMemberAdd', async member => {
  let msg = await member.send(`Hi ${member} welcome to the server Test`);
  await msg.react('✅');
  await msg.react('❎');

  msg.awaitReactions(r => ['✅', '❎'].includes(r.emoji.name), {max: 1})
    .then(collected => {
      let r = collected.first();

      if (r.emoji.name == '✅') 
        member.addRole(member.guild.roles.find("name", "Authorize"))
          .then(() => { console.log(`Added ${member.user.username} (${member.id}).`); })
          .catch(console.error);
      else if (r.emoji.name == '❎') member.kick("You got rejected.");

      r.remove(r.users.last())
    });
});
```