# Do something according to the emoji you reacted with Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying  to create a calendar and depending on the emoji which one we react something happens but I don't find the good function . I try to find in another post but nothing helped me.

Thanks for your help.

This is the code :

```
    if (message.content.startsWith('!agenda')){

        var embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('YELLOW')
            .setTitle('Matter')
            .addFields(
                {name : 'Math :', value: ''},
            )

        var Msg = await message.channel.send(embed);
        Msg.react("");
        var emoji = await Msg.awaitReactions;

        if (emoji === ''){
            message.channel.send('test')
        }
    }   

})
```

Comment: "I don't find the good function" - which function? Up to which point does your code work as expected, where does it start to behave differently?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use awaitReactions in guildMemberAdd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50058056/how-to-use-awaitreactions-in-guildmemberadd)

Comment: The function if try to find is to check if someone react to the message or something like that.
I'm looking the post and I'm trying with this. I'm coming back in few moment. thanks

Comment: I tryed with the answer of the question with that : 
```Msg.awaitReactions(r => [''].includes(r.emoji.name), {max : 1})
        .then(collected => {
            let r = colelcted.first();
        })

        if (r.emoji.name == ''){
            message.channel.send('test')
        }``` but that don't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you are looking for:

```js
message.channel.send(embed).then((m) => {
     m.react(''); //reacts with 

     const filter = (reaction, user) => {
         return user.id != 'put bot id here' || user.id === message.author.id && reaction.emoji.name === '';
     };
     //this filter is to make sure only the user that called the command can react, and the only emoji collected is 

     m.awaitReactions(filter, { max: 1, time: 15000, errors: ['time'] })
     .then(collected => {
         if (collected.first().emoji.name === '') {
             m.channel.send(`:white_check_mark: you reacted with ""`).then(m => m.delete({ timeout: 3000 }));
             //when the user reacts with  - this code is executed
         } else {
             //if the user reacts with any other emoji - remove if you dont want this
             m.channel.send(":x: Command cancelled").then(m => m.delete({ timeout: 3000 }));
         };
     })
        .catch(collected => {
            //if the user does not react in time
            m.channel.send(":x: Command cancelled").then(m => m.delete({ timeout: 3000 }));
     });
});
```

please ask questions if you're confused about any part.

Comment: thanks for the comment that helped me a lot :)

Comment: no problem at all - happy coding!